# Imageview animation running on imageview touch event

Tags: android

Normally `ImageView` touch event work properly but when animation apply on `ImageView` then animating `ImageView` touch event not work.

Please give me suggestion for animating `ImageView` touch event or any event.

Comment: What have you done so far? Post your code you're having trouble with.